Pandas Groupby return incremental numbers of groups as new column
Original DF
| performance | driver_id | season |
|-------------|-----------|--------|
| 1           | 1         | 17     |
| 2           | 1         | 17     |
| 3           | 2         | 17     |
| 4           | 2         | 18     |
| 5           | 2         | 18     |
| 6           | 2         | 19     |
| 7           | 1         | 17     |
| 8           | 1         | 18     |
| 9           | 1         | 18     |

Desired DF
| performance | driver_id | season | season_order |
|-------------|-----------|--------|--------------|
| 1           | 1         | 17     | 1            |
| 2           | 1         | 17     | 1            |
| 3           | 2         | 17     | 1            |
| 4           | 2         | 18     | 2            |
| 5           | 2         | 18     | 2            |
| 6           | 2         | 19     | 3            |
| 7           | 1         | 17     | 1            |
| 8           | 1         | 18     | 2            |
| 9           | 1         | 18     | 2            |

I have a DF where I want to set drivers performances as either first, second, third seasons etc. but this must be differnet for a given driver.
I have tried using cumsum and rank but only help within groups I want between groups ordering/ranking. These methods seem to work better for single column groupbys from my experimenting.
df["season_number"] = (df
                     .groupby(["driver_id ", "season"])
                     .season
                     .transform("rank")
)


This question is similar to: Ranking order per group in Pandas. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Your season_order for driver 2 seems incorrect. You should have 1, 2, 2, 3, no?

@Eoin also it's unclear to me if you should restart the rank when a driver_id changes (e.g. 1 then 2 then 1). If this is the case, you might want to use group = df['driver_id'].ne(df['driver_id'].shift()).cumsum() as grouper.

@mozway yes this is in fact the solution I want, restarted for each driver

@EoinVaughan do you mean for consecutive stretches of each driver? For instance if the last 3 numbers were 18/19/19 instead of 17/18/18 would you want 1/2/2 as output or 2/3/3?

In that scenario 2/3/3

OK, then just group by driver_id.

I think you need GroupBy.rank:
df["season_number"] = df.groupby("driver_id").season.rank(method='dense').astype(int)
print (df)
   performance  driver_id  season  season_number
0            1          1      17              1
1            2          1      17              1
2            3          2      17              1
3            4          2      18              2
4            5          2      18              2
5            6          2      19              3
6            7          1      17              1
7            8          1      18              2
8            9          1      18              2


You should only group by driver_id and use a dense rank:
df['season_number'] = (df.groupby('driver_id')['season']
                         .rank(method='dense').astype(int)
                      )

Output:
   performance  driver_id  season  season_number
0            1          1      17              1
1            2          1      17              1
2            3          2      17              1
3            4          2      18              2
4            5          2      18              2
5            6          2      19              3
6            7          1      17              1
7            8          1      18              2
8            9          1      18              2

